# Why are there inconsistent version results between `which` and directly accessing the executable?

Tags: command-line, macos-highsierra, which

I'm using MacOS High Sierra, and I'm trying to track down a version issue with PHP.  I've come across a very strange situation.  If I `php --version`, it reports 7.4.2.  I then verify where php is being called via `which php`, and then call `php --version` directly, and it reports 7.1.33.  How are these reporting different versions? What is going on?

`php --version`

```
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) (built: Feb 17 2020 12:56:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

`which php`

```
/usr/bin/php
```

`/usr/bin/php --version`

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2020 22:52:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: What is the output of `alias`?

Comment: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Comment: @DavidPostill  `alias` yields:  <br>
    alias pear='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/pear'  
    alias pecl='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/pecl'  
    alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.2.ini"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you, from your `alias` output, that it's pointing you to a different version of php.

```
alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.2.ini'
```

`which` will use the `PATH` environment variable to search for the file, whereas an `alias` will be used if it's configured.

To work around this, you need to use the full path to `php` to use the one in `/usr/bin` or change your `alias`, which may break something else.